# How to configure settings.xml to use custom application in maven project

Tags: spring, maven

I am new for Maven.
I have created two class say *App1* and *App2* in a spring project using Maven build.
How can I configure `settings.xml` to use one of *App1* or *App2* class in my project.
So that if one person wants App1 to use, then he will change `settings.xml` and *App1* will be used by project.

Same, If other person wants to use *App2* then he will make change in `settings.xml` and *App2* will be used by project.

Comment: both files are in same project or not?

Comment: yes both are in same project.

Comment: You do not change settings.xml. For such purposes the pom file is intended. [Please read about the basics of Maven](http://www.sonatype.com/resources/books/maven-the-complete-reference);

Answer (score 1):

Find example here

https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/

or

[How do I add a project as a dependency of another project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383322/maven-how-do-i-add-a-project-as-a-dependency-of-another-project)

Answer (score 0):

What you probably are looking for are [Maven profiles](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Profiles).

However, under normal circumstances you should not use Maven settings.xml for such things. If it is two different applications you should have two Maven projects.